# Given that $\arg\left(z-\frac{uw}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ , draw the locus of points that represent the complex number $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> > Given that $\arg\left(z-\frac{uw}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}$, where $w=3-i$ and $u=-2+2i$ , describe using an equation and then draw the locus of points that represent the complex number $z$

What I have done

$$uw=(3-i)(-2+2i)=-4+8i$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{uw}{2} = \frac{-4+8i}{2}=-2+4i$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -\frac{uw}{2} =2-4i$$

$$ \left(z-\frac{uw}{2}\right)=x+iy+2-4i=(x+2)+i(y-4) $$

Since $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\Im\left(z-\frac{uw}{2}\right)}{\Re\left(z-\frac{uw}{2}\right)}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(y-4)}{(x+2)}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{y-4}{x+2}=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) $$

$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{y-4}{x+2}=1 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow y-4=x+2$$

$$ y=x+6$$

so all I have to do is draw a straight line with a gradient of 1 and $y$ intercept of 6? is this right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{z}-\frac{\left(3-i\right)\left(-2+2i\right)}{2}=\text{z}+2-4i$$

So:

$$\arg\left(\text{z}+2-4i\right)+2\pi\text{k}=\arctan\left(\frac{\Im\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]}{\Re\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]}\right)+2\pi\text{k}=\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi\text{k}$$

Where $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$

So, we know that $\Re\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]>0$ and $\Im\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]>0$:

$$\frac{\Im\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]}{\Re\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]}=1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]-4}{\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+2}=1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\Im\left[\text{z}\right]-\Re\left[\text{z}\right]=6$$

Comment: Uhh I'm not understanding your notation :(

Comment: @dydxx What do you not understandof my notation?

Comment: Hi we both got the same answer right? So is drawing a line of y=x+6 sufficient?

Comment: @dydxx If you mean that $y=\Im\left[\text{z}\right]$ and you've to notice that: $\Re\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]>0$ and $\Im\left[\text{z}+2-4i\right]>0$.

Comment: so because our argument is pi/4 it means for a complex number z=x+iy , (x>0, y>0) so only consider the top half of the graph for example: http://puu.sh/scg4Z/2e57148000.png

Comment: @dydxx Yes, they have to be positive both.